# Trying to declare BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am new in Kotlin Development. I am trying to do a BottomNavigationView, everything works, but when I want to create a BottomNavigationView variable to an ItemSelected Listener, I have the following error :

```
Function invocation 'BottomNavigationView(...)' expected.
```

But in my tutorial it declares like this : `BottomNavigationView bottomNav`

So what's wrong, I don't understand ..
Can you help me please ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with BottomNavigationView?

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you put code here?

Answer (score 0):

**Declare a global variable for bottomViewListener**

'onNavigationItemSelectedListener'

**Initialize and set listener in bottomView in onCreate()**

val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)

```
private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_deals -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

        }
        false
    }
```